# PCL IterativeClosestPoint unable to find nearest neighbour

Tags: ros, icp, pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using the RGBDSLAM from http://www.ros.org/wiki/rgbdslam to create a map with my Kinect. The general ICP implementation provided is a bit buggy so I wanted to replace that with the ICP from PCL. Used the tutorial and everything compiles fine. But when executed the ICP does not converge but outputs this error message:

```
[pcl::IterativeClosestPoint::computeTransformation] Unable to find a nearest neighbour in the target dataset for point 3 in the source!
```

I'd like to narrow down the cause for this, so if anyone has any experience with the parameters of the PCL ICP, I'd really appreciate if you share them! Just so I have an idea what parameters should work for this scenario. If I can rule out wrong parameters (especially max iterations and distance) I can dig into the pointclouds themselves to see if I am somehow messing up target and input cloud or have the wrong transformations or whatever.

I'm using ROS diamondback on Ubuntu 10.10 32bit with the provided PCL.

UPDATE:
I tried several sets of parameters, though nothing seems to impact this. I have saved out two input pointclouds that I try to align with the icp, you can download them [here](http://wwwiaim.ira.uka.de/users/akasper/Misc/Testclouds.zip) if you like. I'm pretty much out of ideas on this. Unfortunately the documentation is rather lacking...

To further clarify what I'm doing:

```
pcl::IterativeClosestPoint<pcl::PointXYZRGB,pcl::PointXYZRGB> icp;
icp.setInputCloud(inputcloud.makeShared());
icp.setInputTarget(targetcloud.makeShared());
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB> final;
icp.align(final);
```

The above download contains inputcloud and targetcloud as they are saved right before icp.align().

UPDATE2:
Using the ICP test sample program and the provided sample files bun0.pcd and bun4.pcd I found out that the problem seems to be specific to my pointclouds as those samples work fine. Are there any preconditions that the pointclouds must fulfill for ICP to work?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10856/pcl-iterativeclosestpoint-unable-to-find-nearest-neighbour/) by [LiMuBei](https://answers.ros.org/users/68/limubei/) on ROS Answers with karma: 261 on 2011-08-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok, since I can also answer my own question, I'll do just that. Apparently the pointclouds I got from the Kinect contained some NaN or Inf values, which the ICP doesn't like. It's kinda obvious that the nearest neighbour search with those values cannot really succeed, a better error message in that case would've saved some time :-)

Anyway, to fix that one can apply a simple passthrough filter to the Kinect pointcloud like this:

```
pcl::PassThrough<pcl::PointXYZRGB> pass; // can do this without parameters
pass.setInputCloud( input );
pass.filter( output );
```

You'll have to do this for both, input and target cloud. Then give the filtered clouds to the ICP.

Alternatively one can use [pcl::removeNaNFromPointCloud](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/group__filters.html#ga1db80ee0ab762ae17b2d6dfd647753eb).

If someone knows a more elegant way to get rid of the NaN or Inf points than that - feel free to edit this post :-)

---

Originally posted by [LiMuBei](https://answers.ros.org/users/68/limubei/) with karma: 261 on 2011-08-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sentinal_Bias](https://answers.ros.org/users/4120/sentinal_bias/) on 2013-06-06**:
i love you